# Django REST Framework: Object level permissions not working according to tutorial

Tags: django, api, python-3.x, permissions, django-rest-framework

I have a basic app that has Users and Tasks and I want TaskDetails to only be accessible by owner. The views, permissions, and settings are as follow:

views.py:

```
from cardinal.permissions import IsOwner

class TaskDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permissions_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                           IsOwner)
```

permissions.py:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("Hit IsOWnerOrReadOnly")
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.owner == request.user


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("Hit IsOwner")
        return obj.owner == request.user


class IsUser(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("Hit IsUser")
        return obj.username == request.user.username
```

settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    #     'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    #     'cardinal.permissions.IsOwnerOrReadOnly',
    #     'cardinal.permissions.IsOwner',
    # ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

When I login as 'Bob', I can access "Susi's" tasks and the permissions don't fire. When I un-comment the default permissions in settings, everything works right but I don't want to set every permission I write as 'Default' for it to work.

I looked at some other answers and one suggested overriding the get_object method within the TaskDetail View with:

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset())
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

When I tried that, I get the error:

```
get() returned more than one Task -- it returned 7!
```

How do I make it so the object-level permissions are being used properly without setting them in the default settings?

**update**

Not sure how or why, but I got it to work by importing the whole app and specifying the full path.

```
import cardinal

class TaskDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = (cardinal.permissions.IsOwner,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues in your code:

First, the error is because you're passing a queryset of more than one object (`Task.objects.all()`) to `get_object_or_404` without specifying one specific pk. [See the third example of this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) in the docs.

Second, you need to raise an error if the permission check doesn't return true. Right now you check the permission but whether it returns `True` or `False` has no impact on the code.

One solution is to do something like the following, assuming your `DetailView`'s URLConf has the `pk` kwarg (if it's different, substitute your overridden kwarg):

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    if self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj):
        return obj
    else:
        raise Http404()
```

Comment: I tried out that code snippet and now whenever I go to a TaskDetail, it returns "detail": "Not found. I put some print statements in, and it hits the else clause, but it never hits the 'IsOwner' permission for any task. Any idea?

Comment: @KyleTruong It sounds like `get_object_or_404` is returning a 404, that's the default response from that function when no object is found.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)` method isn't returning anything. Hence, it must simply be called. It will raise exception if necessary. Otherwise, pass on.